# How to change file ownership using boost library?

Tags: c++, file, boost, ownership, chown

I want to change file ownership using boost library, like **chown()**.
Is there any api for this?

Comment: This question was closed before, incorrectly. Please note that this is about ownership, not permissions. (cf `chmod` vs `chown`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist. Boost's Filesystem doesn't concern itself with owners (or ACLs, for that matter).